# How to save an int to a file and then read it back in android

Tags: android, file-io

I am creating an app and I'm still very new to programming. I was looking around for a long time to find out, how to save an int to a file and then read it back later, but I found nothing. Here's the snippet:

```
int Money = 750;
Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

So when the button is pushed, the int should be saved to a file called `Money.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Shared Preferences if value is used only in this app.

Explanation and example:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: can you flesh this answer out a little more? perhaps explain what Shared Preferences are and how to use them

Answer (score 1):

You should use sqlite DataBase:

[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)